How to conditionally return a promise or a value based on a flag in TypeScript?
I'm working on a TypeScript package called good.db that interfaces with different types of database drivers, some of which are synchronous and some are asynchronous. I want a single method in my class that behaves differently depending on whether the driver is asynchronous or synchronous. Specifically, I want it to:

Return a Promise<boolean> if the driver is asynchronous.
Return a boolean if the driver is synchronous.

Here's a simplified version of my class:
class GoodDB {
    private driver: Drivers;
    public readonly isAsync: boolean;

    constructor(
        driver?: Drivers,
        private options?: goodDBOptions
    ) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.isAsync = checkDriverIsAsync(driver);
        // other something ....
    }

    public async set(key: string, value: any, options?: methodOptions): Promise<boolean>;
    public set(key: string, value: any, options?: methodOptions): boolean;
    public set(key: string, value: any, options?: methodOptions): boolean | Promise<boolean> {
        if (this.isAsync) {
             return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
               // async logic here
             })
        } else {
            // sync logic here
        }
    }
}

Here's how I instantiate the class with different drivers:
const syncDb = new GoodDB(new JSONDriver({ path: './database.json' }));
syncDb.set('key', 'value'); // Should return boolean without needing 'await'

const asyncDb = new GoodDB(new MongoDBDriver({ uri: '...' }));
await asyncDb.set('key', 'value'); // Should return Promise<boolean> and require 'await'

With this setup, TypeScript correctly understands that await is needed when using an asynchronous driver and not needed for a synchronous driver. However, in practice, the TypeScript compiler or linter still suggests using await even when it's not necessary.
I've tried:

Overloading the set method to have different signatures for sync and async operations.
Using a flag (isAsync) to determine whether to call an async or sync implementation internally.

I need a way to ensure that TypeScript's type checking enforces the correct usage of await based on the driver's type. Specifically, I want:

TypeScript to require await when the driver is asynchronous.
TypeScript to not suggest await when the driver is synchronous.

How can I achieve this behavior in TypeScript? Is there a better pattern or approach to conditionally returning a promise or a value in a single method based on a runtime flag?

Do not unleash Zalgo with conditional promises. It's not worth it. You're just trying to add hard to find and diagnose bugs.

I understand your concern, but the current package design is intentional and aims to provide a seamless experience for users working with different drivers. While there are potential complexities, this approach simplifies integration and maintains a unified interface. @VLAZ

But it isn’t a unified interface. It’s trying to be a different interface for synchronous vs asynchronous drivers. Better to treat them all as async and always return a Promise.

Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that doesn't depend on external or private definitions to make sense; right now my IDE is doing a lot of complaining about things like Drivers and goodDBOptions and methodOptions (the latter two are conventionally named, custom types should be UpperCamelCase), etc., as well as JSONDriver and MongoDBDriver. The question therefore risks being closed as lacking sufficient debugging details (and no, a link to external code doesn't suffice).

"I want a single method in my class that behaves differently" - this is a really bad idea. If you really need to support synchronous drivers at all, do it in a separate class, and have your GoodDb factory return either depending on the driver that is passed.

Btw, never pass an async function as the executor to new Promise!
